# displaying 'reactive values' in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The basic idea is to print a value to the end user once the value has changed.

The provided code, generates a shiny dashboard and prints the value 0 to the screen after some seconds. What should I change in order for it to print all the intermediate values (4, 3, 2, 1) before it prints 0? And how would it be best to display the values, rather than just printing?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
x = 5

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(textOutput(outputId = "out"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  while(x > 0){
    x = x - 1
    Sys.sleep(1)
    output$out <- renderPrint(x)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

or a table containing the above, but the actual output is just 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is maybe something that can help you. You have to define a variable outside the `renderPrint`. In my example the variable is change on a timer trigger, but can be any other input. The code is not perfect, the initial loop is executed immediately and you will see 5 and 4 from the beginning, but should be a good start.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
x = 5

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    textOutput(outputId = "out"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "outText"),
    tags$hr(),
    actionButton("go","Change value on click"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "out2")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  # define reactive variable
  outVar <- reactiveValues(dataRow=x,
                           text=paste(x),
                           value = x)
  # define time dependent trigger
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(2000) 

  # render print
  output$out <- renderPrint(outVar$dataRow)
  # render text print
  output$outText <- renderText(outVar$text)
  # render print
  output$out2 <- renderText(outVar$value)


  # time dependent change of variable
  observeEvent(autoInvalidate(),{
    # check if > 0 
    if(outVar$dataRow[length(outVar$dataRow)] > 0){
      # add
      outVar$dataRow <- c(outVar$dataRow,outVar$dataRow[length(outVar$dataRow)]-1)
      outVar$text <- paste0(outVar$text,'\n',outVar$dataRow[length(outVar$dataRow)])
    }
  })

  # observer on click button
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    # check if > 0 
    if(outVar$value > 0){
      # lower by one
      outVar$value <- outVar$value - 1
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexander. Your code does something similar to what I expect. However, the only issue is the requirement that a value should be printed once it has changed and not at a pre-defined time interval.

Comment: I changed the code and added another value which you can change on clicking a button. But as said above, we can change it on any other input. What trigger would you use?

Comment: The trigger would come solely from the server side and not by a click or input by the user. Let's say I retrieve data from a financial API every minute consisting of the current exchange rates between some currency pairs. Some calculations carried out on the server side might point to the an event such as 'exchange GBP for EUR'. I would like the end user to see the quoted text.

Comment: Ok but then the trigger is similar to my timer: You call the api every minute or update the data dump every few minutes.

Comment: You are right, this solves my issue. I would only need to make the function return nothing in case there is no trigger. Thanks!